# How do you install tkinter on PyCharm I have tried all the commands but this is what I get|

Tags: tkinter

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3.9 (from versions:none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3.9-tk

What do I do here?

Comment: `tkinter` is automatically installed when installing python. Do you get an error when you try `import tkinter`? What error is it?

Comment: What is the command you are trying to run? Is it ```pip install python-tk```?

Comment: Tkinter is a module that comes with then install of Python. You should be able to `import tkinter`. If this does not work it may mean your python is not installed correctly or your ide is the problem. I do not use pycharm myself and don't know how it works but is it possible to import in the likes of IDLE

Comment: `tkinter` cannot be installed via `pip`.  If your platform is Linux, try using the system package manager to install the required package.  You need to check the package name for your version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

The tkinter module comes with the installation of python. This means that you do not have to install it manually like you would with something like pygame.
writing:

```
from tkinter import *
```

in pycharm should do allow you to utilize all functions included with the tkinter module.